# I am not able to select any objects in a particular collection in the 3D viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view, selection-tools

I was working on something else other than the airplane and somehow the parts became unselectable in the 3D viewport. I cannot select any part on the airplane in the viewport but I can choose anything else that is not part of the airplane. It's only happening in the airplane's collection. I can select the parts as normal using the outliner, but I cannot do it in the viewport. I don't know if this is a bug. What could be the issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: If the answers don't answer, please share your file

Comment: @moonboots I can't because the file is too big

Comment: remove as many objects as possible and share it on a site like workupload for example

Answer (score 3):

Most probably the collection is marked as `not selectable` in the outliner.
Have a look at the icons on the right handside of the collections line in the outliner and switch the `selectable` icon to `on`.

This is the icon, make sure it is enabled on the collection and all objects further down the hierarchy:

[image: selectable icon]

If you cannot see this icon in your *Outliner*, go to the *Filter* menu (the funnel symbol) and enable it in the *Restriction Toggles*:

[image: restriction toggles]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to select it because it is in the airplane collection, try moving it out into the main collection, or completely moving it out.

Comment: Cool plane by the way!

Comment: We cannot see what makes the objects unselectable, if they themseleves are set to be unselectable and not only the collection, moving them out will not help and even if it did, it makes no sense to disassemble a hierarchical structure that was created for a reason just to make something selectable.